# Renaming Django primary key

Tags: python, django

I am trying to rename the primary key field of a Django model, but I get `django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column "new_name" of relation "my_app_mymodel" does not exist`.

The model is something like this:

```
from django.db import models as django_db_models

class MyModel(django_db_models.Model):
    old_name = django_db_fields.BigAutoField(
                   null=False,
                   primary_key=True,
                   auto_created=True,
                   unique=True,
               )
```

And the migrations is:

```
# Generated by Django 3.2.6 on 2022-10-03 15:33

from django.db import migrations


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('my_app', '0007_previous_migration'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RenameField(
            model_name='mymodel',
            old_name='old_name',
            new_name='new_name',
        ),
    ]
```

Not sure what am I doing wrong. Any ideas?

P.S:
I don't know if this is related but there are foreign keys from other tables to this one.

Comment: I had the same problem yesterday. If you dont mind about losing your database, try to reset it. In my case I had to delete the sql file, as I couldnt get django to accept it. Then try to make the migration to see if this works.

Answer (score 0):

***1 -*** rename the field in the model  :

```
from django.db import models as django_db_models
class MyModel(django_db_models.Model):
    new_name = django_db_fields.BigAutoField(
                   null=False,
                   primary_key=True,
                   auto_created=True,
                   unique=True,
               )
```

***2-*** run `python manage.py makemigrations` (it will just create new migrations based on that  change)

***3-***  then Change the field’s name :

```
operations = [
        migrations.RenameField(
            model_name='mymodel',
            old_name='old_name',
            new_name='new_name',
        ),
```

***4 -*** run `python manage.py migrate` (it will rename the field and keep your data )

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column "new_name" of relation >"my_app_mymodel" does not exist
> ```

When you see the above error message, It means that you've not done the migration yet and you've only created the related migration file for this change. However, you can do this with the following command and then this problem will be solved and you will no longer see this error:

```bash
python manage.py migrate
```